# Reorder items in recyclerView without long press

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I implemented the reorder of items in **recyclerView** using **itemTouchHelper.callback** as it seems to be the most popular solution now. However this allows to reorder only after long press on any item and I need to be able to freely move items around any time (I attach item **itemTouchHelper** for 'edit mode' and detach right after.
What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 9):

first of all disable LongPressDragEnabled in itemTouchHelper and then just call [startDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper#startDrag(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) from on touch of your custom handle view ie Imageview or anything like this

```
viewHolder.dragButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             if (MotionEvent.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                 mItemTouchHelper.startDrag(viewHolder);
             }
             return false;
         }
     });
```

Comment: Thank you. I see one mismatch thing here: dragButton is in item but itemTouchHelper is in recyclerView.
So should I call this from item and expose to the recycler to it?

Comment: you can pass recycler view refrence in adapter or you can also use interface as well to get callback in activity/fragment

Comment: please mark it as answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I did this in adapter. I see onTouch calls in debugger and that viewHolder is not null but dragging doesn't actually start. Of course I disabled LongPressDrag.